# bootstrap tabs, not working on responsive view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to responsive CSS. 
I am creating a project using bootstrap css.

1) When I click(on mobile view) on the tabs, it doesn't work, but it's working on my laptop browser.

2) I am not sure, if that's how it's (tab section of below link) suppose to be looking on mobile view.

You can visit the below link, you have to scroll down and you will see 5 tabs, that's the section which is messed up on responsive view.

http://designersabode.com/animation-prime.html

Comment: What do you mean by messed up? please specify. and what is the expected result you looking for? Please share with the community. As far as I can see the site looks ok on the mobile view

Comment: edite my question see, if it makes any sense to you @Yashchaturvedi

Comment: Are you using a template for this? Because in bootstrap the menu tends to shrink to a hamburger menu like the one here on mobile screens. But it has different behaviour depending on your code or the template you are using. If the template you are using has this kind of behavior then your menu is behaving correctly. This is what the menu I created behaves like https://www.simplystamps.com/

Comment: Hey i am giving you a link for your reference for responsive view of bootstrap tabs.   Ref : https://jsfiddle.net/fr0w59n9/